# Javascript, different between b^2 and b * b

Tags: javascript, math

I try coding in Javascript to find the result of a second linear regression and found the result as attached:

[image: Using b ^ 2]

[image: Using b * b]

and the result is different ???

Answer (score 6):

This is because the `^` operator is not how Javascript does powers. The `^`  operator is the bitwise [XOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_XOR) operator.

To square a value you would need to use `Math.pow()` or `**`. As in:

```
b * b
Math.pow(b, 2);
b ** 2
```

Comment: Or `**`, for the latest ECMAScript version.

Comment: @ChhuonSahakThun don't forget to accept the solution that works for you.

Answer (score 3):

1. `*` is arithmetic [multiplication](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Multiplication_(*)) operator.
2. `^` is bitwise [XOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_XOR) operator.
3. To raise a number to a power use arithmetic [exponentiation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Exponentiation_(**)) operator `**` (introduced in ECMAScript 7 - [see browser support](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/)) or [`Math.pow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) function.